# Style lines differently when intersecting a polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, contour

I want to give my contour lines a blue colour on glaciers (inside the polygon that shows the outlines of the glaciers) - and a brown colour everywhere else. What is the easiest way to achieve this? I am using ArcMap 10.5.1.

[image]

---

Here is my result using arctoolbox - analysis tools - extract - clip.

[image]

Comment: The [Erase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/erase.htm) and [Clip](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm) tools would allow you to extract the contours that dot not overlap and those that overlap glaciers as separate layers, and you could symbolize them with different colors afterwards.

Comment: You could also use Union with the glacier polygon to add another field for compound symbolization.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to do the job by using the clip tool. i will also try to use Union - to see whether I´ll get a similar  result.

Comment: @Helga Davids you can write up an answer to your own question if you like. That helps if someone else has the same question in the future.